# How to enable CSS3 transitions in internet explorer 10?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, animation, internet-explorer-10, transition

I'm trying to reproduce this effect: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DShadingWithBoxShadows/

Can anyone suggest the exact method as to how to make the CSS3 transitions work correctly on Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: What are you trying to do *specifically*?

Comment: Andre..

check this link once in Chrome and then in IE10
u will see a difference in them.......in IE10 the transition is not working correctly like in the other browsers.

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DShadingWithBoxShadows/

Comment: [IE10 does not support the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

Comment: is there any alternative for it??

Comment: [There doesn't appear to be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687399/workaround-for-missing-preserve-3d-property-in-ie-10).

Answer (score 3):

**You do not need to add anything more** than the [Standard syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279623.aspx) to make it work in IE10.
In fact, IE10, like the other vendor products, supports the shorthand animation property alone as well.

Visit  :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279623.aspx for more details.

To know the different syntax comparison and version compatibility, please see below :

```
Chrome
    1.0 (-webkit prefix)

Firefox
    4.0 (2.0) (-moz prefix)
    16.0 (16.0) (no prefix)

Internet Explorer
    10.0 (no prefix)

Opera
    10.5 (-o prefix)  
    12.0 (no prefix)

Safari
    3.2 (-webkit prefix)
```

Comment: Roy M J 
I was reading an article which explained 3D shading with box-shadows

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DShadingWithBoxShadows/

if you open this link  once in chrome and then in Internet Explorer 10, you will see that only the front div is visible in IE10 

what is the problem in it...plzz tell??

Comment: The article appears to not be using the correct property for perspective in IE10. It's a little bit different - This should help - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx